# C# Transparency in XP

Tags: c#, transparency, splash-screen

I have a little splash window:

```
public partial class Splash : Form
{

  bool painted = false;

  public Splash()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
  {
    //
  }

  protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
  {
    if (painted)
        return;

    Graphics gfx = e.Graphics;
    gfx.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.Splash, ClientRectangle);
    painted = true;
  }
}
```

`Properties.Resources.Splash` is a PNG with alpha, and displays beautifully on my Windows 7 development computer.

On the Windows XP target computers, however, there is no transparency; instead, the background of the image is black.

I know it's possible to display a transparent splash window in XP because I have seen it before. Is it possible to do it in .net? If so, how?

Comment: I don't think XP supports windows with a full alpha channel. You can use color keying to set one 100% transparent color but other than that you're out of luck. Most older programs used a small trick for such splash screens with alpha blending: Create a screenshot where your window is going to appear and use that for background drawing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with WS_EX_LAYERED but requires some efforts and some P/Invoke: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx

Also there is an older article here but don't know if it's still valid: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/transparentwindowsincsharp.aspx

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer since it is a good answer - but I have not tested it and am not using it. I did, however, implement Mario's comment on my question which worked very well and was easy to implement. Looking at other commercial software, it seems like they are generally using Mario's method of taking a screenshot of that area.

Comment: Link only answer specially if they are linking to Microsoft websites which articles tend to disappear all the time, is not a goo idea. please include the detail here if possible.